The OUTLINE ie. chat icon is not displayed in teams bot app
The OUTLINE icon displayed earlier is not showing now after updating the teams app.
The configuration in .env file:
CONFIG__MANIFEST__ICONS__OUTLINE=resources/BotLogoSmall.png
The configuration in Manifest file :
        "color": "${{CONFIG__MANIFEST__ICONS__COLOR}}",
        "outline": "${{CONFIG__MANIFEST__ICONS__OUTLINE}}"
    },```


The image BotLogoSmall.png is in the resource folder. This image has been displayed properly for more than a year. Now, suddenly, without any change in the bot source code or recent publishing of the bot in the Partner Center, the image is not displayed



 We tried the following things:

(1) We cleared all the team's cache

(2) Go to your bot in Azure>> to settings on the left-hand side - you will see the first option to upload a custom bot icon. This will update your icon.

But still, the OUTLINE icon is not displayed. I have marked it in the attached image.




